# SSO forms authentication token used in angular 7

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, forms-authentication

I am new to angular and I would like to know if this is possible.  I have an SSO using a forms authentication  which I use to authenticate in MVC web applications.  Can I use this existing authentication to provide SSO to my new angular web apps?  If it is possible please give me some ideas on how to implement this.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a token (JWT) that is passed to the angular client application and is used to authenticate future requests.

At a high level we perform the forms authentication and on successful login we respond to the client with the JWT which is stored into session storage. Then the application is redirected to our angular SPA which has a Guard that loads the token from storage and authenticates the session or redirects the user back to the login page if the JWT is missing or expired.

We use this lib to help with JWT "stuff" on the angular side (check for expiration, etc.).
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

You can see an example here:
https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-1/

Comment: How did you handle token across domain in angular app?

Comment: @wickdninja Thanks for the reply and ideas.  I have difficulty on saving a JWT token in local storage in an MVC Controller. Can you give me any samples on doing it an MVC Controller.  Thank you

Comment: The MVC controller doesn't save to local storage. You would have to have a controller action that returns the JWT to angular application. The client side angular application store the token and uses said token to make subsequent API calls to your API controllers.

Comment: A good sample that demostrates this approach can be seen here: https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-1/

Comment: Thanks @wickdninja for the clarification and link.  It was a great help.